# Reports and dashboard: MY cases vs My company cases

Tags: dashboard, report-chart

I want to create a report that shows the number of cases created by a single user versus the total number of cases created by other users in the same account (company cases). The dashboard will then display this information in a donut chart and percentage values. I tried using a formula field and using it to filter the report but didn't quite get right. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Did you try bucket fields?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, the issue with using a bucket will be that the value in the bucket will be hardcoded to a specific user. The aim of this dashboard is to show a currently logged in user their cases vs company cases (total of all other users cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is with. a new custom formula checkbox field on Case

```
Is_Created_By_Me__c

defined as: CreatedById = $User.Id
```

Then your report/dash merely counts Cases where `Is_Created_By_Me__c` = `true` vs `false`

Comment: I created a similar formula field createdby.id = $User.id, "my case", "my team case", both seem to solve my problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: cool -- SFSE convention is to mark the answer as Accepted (see check mark) if it solved your issue. This helps others with a similar question